# Check if input field value exist in array, if so return to page with an error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a form where user insert their names, once they submit the form, the page should check if the name provided already exists, if so, should return with an error, other wise, proceed normally.

How do I check if my input value exists and stop the form if this exists?

```
<?php

$array = get_meta_values( 'user_submit_name' );
// Array to search:
// Temp array so we don't find the same key multipule times:
$temp = array();
// Iterate through the array:
foreach ($array as $key)
{
// Check the key hasn't already been found:
if (!in_array($key, $temp))
{
    // Get an array of all the positions of the key:
    $keys = array_keys($array, $key);
    // Check if there is more than one position:
    if (count($keys)>0)
    {
        // Add the key to the temp array so its not found again:
        $temp[] = $key;
        // Do something...
        echo '<li>Name already used';                        
    }
}
}
?>
```

html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="usp_form" method="post" data-validate="parsley" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label  class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="user-submitted-name">Il tuo nome</label>
             <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input name="user-submitted-name" type="text" value="" data-required="true" required placeholder="Your name" class="form-control input-lg usp-input">
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
            <input class="submit btn btn-lg btn-primary" name="user-submitted-post" id="user-submitted-post" type="submit" value="<?php _e('Submit', 'usp'); ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If I understood correctly by *"stop the form if this exists?"* Instead of using `echo '<li>Name already used';` you could either use `die("<li>Name already used");` or put an `exit` at the end like this `echo '<li>Name already used'; exit;` - Both of those will stop your form from executing/going any further.

Comment: ok thanks that's a step closer and it makes perfect sense but how do I compare the input value with that array?

Comment: You're welcome. Seems like you're already doing it now with `if (!in_array($key, $temp))` aren't you? If not, just use either an `else` or reverse the condition, as in `if (in_array($key, $temp))` or `elseif`

Comment: i'm checking the array yes but I haven't said anywhere to check the input value against that array

Comment: Hm... maybe something to the affect of `if (!in_array($key, $temp) && exist($_POST['user-submitted-name']))` or use `||` instead of `&&` am not entirely sure but that's what I'm under the impression of what you're trying to achieve. I would recommend you not using hyphens for field names, use underscores as much as you can. It could cause problems down the road.

Comment: should I not check with if (isset ?

Comment: Usually an `if(isset` is used with a submit button. You can probably try that, or check with an `if(empty` instead, that way it will check if it's empty or not. And if it is left empty, then echo an error message. You could easily add that condition with an `&&` or `||`. `&&-AND` `||-OR` in the `if` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it from your comments that you have the following:

```
$_POST["user-submitted-name"]; // name from the form
$names = get_meta_values('user_submit_name'); // array with names not allowed
```

Then it looks like the easy way:

```
if (in_array($_POST["user-submitted-name"], $names)) {
    // posting not allowed
    echo '<li>Name already used';
} else {
    // posting is allowed
    // save posting here...
    // and then go to success page:
    header("Location: success.html"); // redirect
    exit(); // and stop here
}
```

Comment: should I not check with if (isset ?

Comment: see the point is this is included within the same page as per the actual form

Comment: Yes, the usual setup: Form posts to itself, and only activates the action if the validation is passed. And that is exactly what I'm suggesting, but I see my code is lacking one important thing...

Comment: i'm having no luck with it, it is posting with success even tho the name is already used. Let me get this right, i paste this code within the form template, but i'm not sure how i should say in plain words "when submit button is clicked, run this to check"

Comment: Ok, while googling for a tutorial I found this: http://www.montanaprogrammer.com/php-web-programming/php-form-validation/ and it seems you already used it and it misleads you now. That tutorial has a special method of validation implemented that you don't need. The validation in the tutorial checks whether only allowed fields are posted, and if some of them are filled. But the general workflow is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just make use of a multi-level **`break`** statement and come out of the loop.

Something like

```
if (count($keys)>0)
    {
        // Add the key to the temp array so its not found again:
        $temp[] = $key;
        // Do something...
        echo '<li>Name already used';  
        break 3;                      
    }
```

Comment: what's "break 3" ? I know break but what's the number?

Comment: Number of nested loops you are inside. You are inside an `if`, `if` and a `for`.

Comment: according to this only says break 1 and 2 http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: so how do I compare the value in the input field tho?

Comment: Don't use that break command suggested. It will make your code unreadable.

Comment: @Sven actually that break won't even solve my question; on submission, I need to check the value of an input field (name) against an array of names i get here: $array = get_meta_values( 'user_submit_name' ); and if the value is already present, stop the submission and display an error, otherwise, submit

Comment: @rob.m [See my comment then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816193/check-if-input-field-value-exist-in-array-if-so-return-to-page-with-an-error#comment27753128_18816193) (*From 5 mins. ago*)